# Are there any data sets available for download of all addresses that have been used?

Tags: etherscan, addresses, data

Since etherscan indexes all addresses that have been involved in any transaction i was wondering if such a data set is available for download anywhere?

I cant find anything on etherscans website and google hasnt turned up much.

If there is no data set available i think my only other option would be to spin up a node and trawl through each block.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up and retrieve the data for **Ethereum Cumulative Unique Addresses** [here](https://ycharts.com/indicators/ethereum_cumulative_unique_addresses) - otherwise yeah, use a blockchain scaling platform like [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) or [Infura](https://www.infura.io/), spin up a node and get trawlin'

Answer (score 0):

There's a dataset in Google itself (BigQuery): https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/ethereum/crypto-ethereum-blockchain

Currently, https://github.com/blockchain-etl/ethereum-etl is still active.

Documentation is at http://ethereum-etl.readthedocs.io

A 2018 article by its creator: https://evgemedvedev.medium.com/ethereum-blockchain-on-google-bigquery-283fb300f579

Other project contacts in case the Github disappears:

- https://t.me/BlockchainETL
- https://discord.gg/tRKG7zGKtF